# Python- I have a dataset having two columns length and count. I want to find the distribution of the given dataset

Tags: python, scipy, distribution

All the articles present are about the 1D data for example list.But my data is of type

| length | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 12 |
| 10 | 4 |

I tired to create a list by repeating the length according to the given count and then using scipy to fit the distribution but it was taking too much time as it was a large dataset.

Comment: Are you trying to say you have 12 things of length 5 and 4 things of length 10?  What information do you want to get out of that?  What do YOU mean by "find the distriibution"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is all the data you have, and you would like to find the distribution of the "length"-
The distribution is 5+5*Bernoulli(0.25)

I calculated it without writing a thing, let me explain:
You only have 2 possible values, which means you can describe it as a linear combination of the Bernoulli distribution.

How can we find the parameters?
The difference between the values is the added 5.

The 0.25 is the percentage (25%) of the "1" out of the data:
4/(4+12) = 4/16 = 0.25

Comment: This is wrong, of course. Right answer is 5*(1+Bernoulli(p=1/4)).

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread my handwriting notes. Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a histogram of your data to study the distribution. Histogram mean to project you table onto "length" but using "Count" as weights. Use, e.g. Dataframe plot for this

```
df["length"].plot(kind="hist", weights=df["Count"])
```

Depending on your data and the actual distribution of "length" you will need to tune the parameters of the historgram. Use the "ax" parameter for this. See
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

When you have the histogram you could share it here. Or you immediately see if is is Gaussian -- or not. Use fitting only then, and only if needed. Also remember, fitting will always "just" return an approximated, simplified model (if you data is not trivial).

Comment: "You need to make a histogram of your data" it is already histogram of the data - this is what Count is for